# Python UiPath - How to use Classes with UiPath.Python.Activities

Tags: python, uipath

Here is an image showing Python scope activity (version 3.6 and target x64):

Python Scope

[image]

The main problem is the relation between both invoke python methods, the first one is used to start the class object, and the second one to access a method of that class. Here is an image of the first invoke python properties:

Invoke Python init method

[image]

And the getNumberPlusOne activity call:

Invoke Python getNumberPlusOne method

[image]

The python code being executed:

```py
class ExampleClass:
    def __init__(self,t,n):
        self.text = t
        self.number = n

    def getNumberPlusOne(self):
        return (self.number+1)
```

And finally, the error when executing the second Invoke Python Method:

> An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Error invoking Python method ----> System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: Type 'UiPath.Python.PythonObject' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.

Any idea about where is the mistake and how to interact with the output object created in the init method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this activity was designed with simple scripts in mind, not with entire classes. [Here's](https://forum.uipath.com/t/python-script-with-class-and-object/111110/3) an article on their Community Forum where user Sergiu.Wittenberger goes into more details.

Let's start with the Load Python Script activity:
[image: invoke python script]

In my case the local variable "pyScript" is a pointer to the python object, i.e. an instance of `ExampleClass`.

Now, there is the Invoke Python Method activity - this one allows us to call a method by name. It seems however that methods on the class are inaccessible to UiPath - you can't just type `pyScript.MethodName()`.
[image: invoke python method]

So it seems that we can't access class methods (please proof me wrong here!), but there's a workaround as shown by Sergio. In your case, you would add another method outside your class in order to access or manipulate your object:

```py
class ExampleClass:
    def __init__(self,t,n):
        self.text = t
        self.number = n

    def getNumberPlusOne(self):
        return (self.number+1)


foo = ExampleClass("bar", 42)

def get_number_plus_one():
    return foo.getNumberPlusOne()
```

Note that this also means that the object is instantiated within the very same file: `foo`. At this point this seems to be the only option to interact with an object -- again, I'd hope somebody can prove me wrong.

For the sake of completeness, here's the result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Wolfgang, this helped. It works how you said.

Comment: Sure thing. Please consider checking this as the accepted answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to what the above user said that you have to make sure that the imports you use are in the global site-packages, and not in a venv as Studio doesn't have access to that.

Moreoever, always add this:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```

to the beginning of your code. Again, a limitation of the implementation. (docs here: https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/load-script)

Doing this you might be able to do more complicated structures I think, but I haven't tested this out.